# ARKit - ARReferenceImage Tracking

Tags: swift, arkit, ios11

I'm playing around with ARReferenceImages in ARKit and I'm trying to add an SCNNode when a reference image is recognised and then leave that node in place regardless of whether the same reference image is then recognised elsewhere.

I can add my SCNode correctly, but if I move my marker it picks it up again and moves my placed node to the position of the marker.

My code to add is as follows:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
        let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage
        print("MAPNODE IS NIL = \(self.mapNode == nil)")
        updateQueue.async {
            if self.mapNode == nil {

            // Create a plane to visualize the initial position of the detected image.
            let plane = SCNPlane(width: 1.2912,
                                 height: 1.2912)
            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
            planeNode.opacity = 1

            /*
             `SCNPlane` is vertically oriented in its local coordinate space, but
             `ARImageAnchor` assumes the image is horizontal in its local space, so
             rotate the plane to match.
             */
            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

            self.mapNode = planeNode
            /*
             Image anchors are not tracked after initial detection, so create an
             animation that limits the duration for which the plane visualization appears.
             */
            // Add the plane visualization to the scene.
            node.addChildNode(planeNode)
            }
        }
 }
```

reading the docs here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience#2958517 it states that

> Apply Best Practices
>
> This example app simply visualizes where ARKit detects each reference
>   image in the user’s environment, but your app can do much more. Follow
>   the tips below to design AR experiences that use image detection well.
>
> Use detected images to set a frame of reference for the AR scene.
>   Instead of requiring the user to choose a place for virtual content,
>   or arbitrarily placing content in the user’s environment, use detected
>   images to anchor the virtual scene. You can even use multiple detected
>   images. For example, an app for a retail store could make a virtual
>   character appear to emerge from a store’s front door by recognizing
>   posters placed on either side of the door and then calculating a
>   position for the character directly between the posters.
>
> Note
>
> Use the ARSession setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform:) method to
>   redefine the world coordinate system so that you can place all anchors
>   and other content relative to the reference point you choose.
>
> Design your AR experience to use detected images as a starting point
>   for virtual content. ARKit doesn’t track changes to the position or
>   orientation of each detected image. If you try to place virtual
>   content that stays attached to a detected image, that content may not
>   appear to stay in place correctly. Instead, use detected images as a
>   frame of reference for starting a dynamic scene. For example, your app
>   might recognize theater posters for a sci-fi film and then have
>   virtual spaceships appear to emerge from the posters and fly around
>   the environment.

So I tried setting my world transform to be equal to the transform of my image anchor

```
 self.session.setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: imageAnchor.transform)
```

However my mapNode follows the imageAnchor where ever it moves. I haven't implemented the `renderer update` method so I'm not sure why this keeps moving.

I'm assuming that the `setWorldOrigin` method is constantly updating to the imageAnchor.transform and not just that moment in time, which is weird as that code is only called once. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the mapNode at the position of the `ARImageAnchor` you could set the position of your mapNode at the transform of the `ARImageAnchor` and add it to the scene but not linked to the reference image  if that makes sense.

This could be done like so:

```
 func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        //1. If Out Target Image Has Been Detected Than Get The Corresponding Anchor
        guard let currentImageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

        //2. An ImageAnchor Is Only Added Once For Each Identified Target
        print("Anchor ID = \(currentImageAnchor.identifier)")

        //3. Add An SCNNode At The Position Of The Identified ImageTarget
        let nodeHolder = SCNNode()

        let nodeGeometry = SCNBox(width: 0.02, height: 0.02, length: 0.02, chamferRadius: 0)
        nodeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
        nodeHolder.geometry = nodeGeometry

        nodeHolder.position = SCNVector3(currentImageAnchor.transform.columns.3.x,
                                         currentImageAnchor.transform.columns.3.y,
                                         currentImageAnchor.transform.columns.3.z)

        augmentedRealityView?.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(nodeHolder)

 }
```

In another part of your question you seem to imply that you want to detect multiple occurrences of the same image. I could be wrong but I think the only way to do this is to remove the corresponding `ARImageAnchor` for the reference image, which can be done like so (by adding it at the end of the last code snippet):

```
 augmentedRealitySession.remove(anchor: currentImageAnchor)
```

The issue here is that once the `ARImageAnchor` is removed, any time it is detected again, you would have to handle whether content should be added, which is tricky since the `ARImageAnchor.identifier` is always the same for the `referenceImage` regardless of whether it is removed and then re-added thus making it difficult to store in a `dictionary` etc. As such depending on your needs you would then need to find a way to determine if content existed at that location and whether to re add it etc.

The last part of your question about `setWorldOrigin` seems a bit odd like you said, but maybe you could add a Bool to prevent it from potentially changing e.g:

```
var hasSetWorldOrigin = false
```

Then based on this you could ensure that it is only set once e.g:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        //1. If Out Target Image Has Been Detected Than Get The Corresponding Anchor
        guard let currentImageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }


        //2. If We Havent Set The World Origin Set It Based On The ImageAnchorTranform
        if !hasSetWorldOrigin{

            self.augmentedRealitySession.setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: currentImageAnchor.transform)
            hasSetWorldOrigin = true

            //3. Create Two Nodes To Add To The Scene And Distribute Them
            let nodeHolderA = SCNNode()
            let nodeGeometryA = SCNBox(width: 0.04, height: 0.04, length: 0.04, chamferRadius: 0)
            nodeGeometryA.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
            nodeHolderA.geometry = nodeGeometryA

            let nodeHolderB = SCNNode()
            let nodeGeometryB = SCNBox(width: 0.04, height: 0.04, length: 0.04, chamferRadius: 0)
            nodeGeometryB.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
            nodeHolderB.geometry = nodeGeometryB

            if let cameraTransform = augmentedRealitySession.currentFrame?.camera.transform{
                nodeHolderA.simdPosition =  float3(cameraTransform.columns.3.x,
                                                   cameraTransform.columns.3.y,
                                                   cameraTransform.columns.3.z)

                nodeHolderB.simdPosition =  float3(cameraTransform.columns.3.x + 0.2,
                                                   cameraTransform.columns.3.y,
                                                   cameraTransform.columns.3.z)
            }


            augmentedRealityView?.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(nodeHolderA)
            augmentedRealityView?.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(nodeHolderB)
        }

}
```

Hopefully my answer will provide a useful starting point to you assuming of course I have interpreted your question correctly,

Comment: Hey, no I didn't want to detect multiple instances of the same anchor, I was just mentioning that because it moves my mapNode that I thought it was detecting it multiple times. I'll try out your answer when I can and let you know how I get on. Thanks for taking the time to answer

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Ironically all I needed to do was just add it to the rootNode of the scene via `self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)` I didn't need the extra position stuff. Thanks again

Comment: Cool glad you got it sorted :)